# A huge separator in a comparative view screenshot

Tags: visualization, paraview

I am comparing 3 contour plots; each of them is represented in a comparative panel.
The following picture shows my setting:

[image]

Since I want to capture a screenshot of the entire layout, I have to choose the **separator width**. Even though I select `1` as the separator width, ParaView generates the following picture:

[image]

in which we observe two huge separator sizes.
It seems that ParaView is compensating a sort of *extra empty space*.

What am I missing? Which feature should I consider in order to get smaller separators?

I am using ParaView 5.10.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Wich version of ParaView are you using ?

Comment: I am using ParaView 5.10.

Comment: try ParaView 5.11.0

Comment: @MathieuWestphal it seems that some underlying graphical option is "wrong". If I adjust all the comparative windows such that they have the same size, the separators are alll the same. If your reproduction is different could you please share the settings you have adopted?

Comment: run ParaView; wavelet, Apply; split in three; File -> Save Screenshot; Save All Views; save.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal unfortunately I get the same outcome.